# Using Nodemailer - Email is sent but not recieved

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, backend, nodemailer

I am using a custom email on a custom domain and trying to send emails to clients. On the node side the response shows the email is sent but can't see it on the reciever's input box.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'mail.example.com', 
port: '587',  
secure: true , 
auth: {
user: "noreply@example.com", 
pass: 'password' },
tls:   rejectUnauthorized:false , 
           }
            
            
       });
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
                    if (error) return 400; 
                    
                    else {
                        
                        console.log(info) ;
                        return 200 ; 
                    }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the code that is able to send messages? There is a `{` missing in key `tls`.

And try changing the port to `465` (Though it's deprecated)

Comment: Yeah, I think I made a mistake in pasting the code, the code is correct as far as I know.

Comment: Can you provide the log?

Comment: accepted: [ 'msraut2002@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 83,
  messageTime: 36,
  messageSize: 371,
  response: '250 OK id=1nRrFr-003Iu7-Lj',
  envelope: { from: 'noreply@example.in', to: [ 'msraut2002@gmail.com' ] },
  messageId: '<7bc4c7fa-28b5-79da-3c12-fd98ce92851c@example.in>'

Comment: Yeah, the log says the message is sent(if you have changed the from field before pasting it here). Please check your mailbox's spam section. There should be the email.

Comment: Yeah I have changed the from email, and also I have checked the spam box. It's not there.

Answer (score 0):

found out the issue. idk why, but when I added the optional parameter in transporter:                                                                                                              name: "www.domain.com"
it started working.